# Is there a token standard that allow for future minting and burning of tokens?

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-20, erc-777

I am interested in an ethereum token with the functionality for an operator to mint new supply at any time. It would also be nice if the operator could burn supply explicitly rather than sending to an address. Is there a standard for this type of token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ERC777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777) provides guidelines for minting and burning of tokens.  Here are excerpts from ERC777:

**Minting Tokens**

```
Minting tokens is the act of producing new tokens.
[ERC777] intentionally does not define specific functions to mint tokens.
This intent comes from the wish not to limit the use of the [ERC777] standard
as the minting process is generally specific for every token.

Nonetheless, the rules below MUST be respected when minting for a *recipient*:

- Tokens MAY be minted for any *recipient* address (except `0x0`).

- The total supply MUST be increased by the amount of tokens minted.

- The balance of `0x0` MUST NOT be decreased.

- The balance of the *recipient* MUST be increased by the amount of tokens minted.

- The token contract MUST emit a `Minted` event with the correct values as defined in the [`Minted` Event][minted].

- The token contract MUST call the `tokensReceived` hook of the *recipient*
  if the *recipient* registers an `ERC777TokensRecipient` implementation via [ERC1820].

- The `data` and `operatorData` MUST be immutable during the entire mint process -- hence the same `data` and `operatorData` MUST be used to call the `tokensReceived` hook and emit the `Minted` event.
```

**Burning Tokens**

```
Burning tokens is the act of destroying existing tokens.
[ERC777] explicitly defines two functions to burn tokens (`burn` and `operatorBurn`).
These functions facilitate the integration of the burning process in wallets and dapps.
However, the token contract MAY prevent some or all *holders* from burning tokens for any reason.
The token contract MAY also define other functions to burn tokens.

The rules below MUST be respected when burning the tokens of a *holder*:

- Tokens MAY be burned from any *holder* address (except `0x0`).

- The total supply MUST be decreased by the amount of tokens burned.

- The balance of `0x0` MUST NOT be increased.

- The balance of the *holder* MUST be decreased by amount of tokens burned.

- The token contract MUST emit a `Burned` event with the correct values as defined in the [`Burned` Event][burned].

- The token contract MUST call the `tokensToSend` hook of the *holder*
  if the *holder* registers an `ERC777TokensSender` implementation via [ERC1820].

- The `operatorData` MUST be immutable during the entire burn process&mdash;hence
  the same `operatorData` MUST be used to call the `tokensToSend` hook and emit the `Burned` event.

The token contract MUST `revert` when burning in any of the following cases:

- The *operator* address is not an authorized operator for the *holder*.

- The resulting *holder* balance after the burn is not a multiple of the *granularity*
  defined by the token contract.

- The balance of *holder* is inferior to the amount of tokens to burn
  (i.e., resulting in a negative balance for the *holder*).

- The address of the *holder* is `0x0`.

- The `tokensToSend` hook of the *holder* `revert`s.
```

ERC777 encourages compatibility with ERC20.  There are additional requirements for minting and burning that are specified in the [full text of ERC777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777), that have been omitted from this answer.